# Binding JSON JArray to Listview in UWP Issue

Tags: c#, json, listview, uwp, win-universal-app

In visual studio universal windows app, I am trying to bind a JArray to a Listview. It seems to compile fine and the quantity of rows populate into the Listview but no data fills the rows. What am I doing wrong here or is this even possible?

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

XAML

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lstJobData">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="8">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=job_id}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=job_number}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=ship_type}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>        
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

JArray from Service layer (converted to Jarray from Json string)

```
{[
  { "job_id": 399783, "job_number": "XYZ-J111111", "ship_type": "c" },
  { "job_id": 445672, "job_number": "XYZ-J222222", "ship_type": "p" },
  { "job_id": 896543, "job_number": "XYZ-J333333", "ship_type": "f" }
]}
```

XAML (Code behind)

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyServices.Service1Client client = new MyServices.Service1Client();
    var itemSource = await client.GetDTAsync();
    JArray result = JArray.Parse(itemSource);

    lstJobData.ItemsSource = result;

}
```

Comment: the json which you provided doesn't correct

Comment: Also, please, add `JArray` class

Answer (score 0):

When we set the `JArray` to the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView`, we can not use the path in the XAML. The path means Property-path, it will point to the property of the item. Also there is no `job_id` property in the item.

If you want to use path in XAML, we should be able to create a `Job` class. And in the `Job`, we should be able to define the `job_id`, `job_number` and 
`ship_type` properties.
Then we should be able to add the `Job` to the `ObservableCollection` of the `Job` class.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button1_Click" >click</Button>
    <ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lstJobData">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="8">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=job_id}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=job_number}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=ship_type}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Job> Jobs;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string newJson = @"
        [
            {'job_id':399783,'job_number':'XYZ-J111111','ship_type':'c'},
            {'job_id':445672,'job_number':'XYZ-J222222','ship_type':'p'},
            {'job_id':896543,'job_number':'XYZ-J333333','ship_type':'f'}
        ]";
        JArray result = JArray.Parse(newJson);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            Jobs.Add(new Job() { job_id = (string)result[i]["job_id"], job_number = (string)result[i]["job_number"], ship_type = (string)result[i]["ship_type"] });
        }

        lstJobData.ItemsSource = Jobs;
    }
}

internal class Job
{
    public string job_id { get; set; }
    public string job_number { get; set; }
    public string ship_type { get; set; }
}
```